# Merging 2 javascripts into one

Tags: javascript, checkbox, setinterval

I have 2 javascripts working but want to merge them into one.
The purpose of the script is to make a checkbox that changes the a varable for the refresh rate.

Script 1 (works as expected)

```
        window.onload = function () {
    var input = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');

    function check() {
        if (input.checked) {
            var timeout = "10000";
        } else {
            var timeout = "999999";
        }
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'result ' + timeout;
    }
    input.onchange = check;
    check();
}

<input type="checkbox" value="1" />Checkbox
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Script 2 (works as expected)

```
var timeout = 10000; 
var action = function() {
$('#content').load('/arduino/refresh');
}; 
setInterval(action, timeout);
```

I tought I could just merge them together and let them live happily ever after so I created the following script: (it shows the checkbox but checking/unchecking does not change the refresh rate)

```
            window.onload = function () {
        var input = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');

        function check() {
            if (input.checked) {
                var timeout = "10000";
            } else {
                var timeout = "999999";
            }
                var action = function() {
    $('#content').load('/arduino/refresh');
    }; 
        }
        input.onchange = check;
        check();
    }
setInterval(action, timeout);

<input type="checkbox" value="1" />Checkbox
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

In the combined script, `setInterval` is not called within the `check` event handler.  The local variable `timeout` is modified, but the new value is never used to actually change the refresh rate.

Also, use `clearInterval` and `setInterval` together when changing the refresh rate.

Comment: Hi Joel.
Thanks for taking the time to reply.
I'm not sure if I understood you correctly and changed 1 part to:
        input.onchange = check;
        check();
setInterval(action, timeout);
    }

But that caused the setInterval to stop.

Comment: You need it in both places, actually.  Once when the page loads and again in the check handler.

Comment: And also, in the check handler, make sure to use clearInterval to remove the old timer before using setInterval to add the new one.  Check the documentation for these methods for more  information.